# if statement with parser class on view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with `codeigniter`  and I'm  wondering if I can use `if statement` on a view  like twig ( without `twig`) using the [parser class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html) or what is the best approach to do it?

In the controller

```
 public function peajes()
 {
    $data = array(
        'booleanVariable' => true,
     );
    $this->parser->parse('myView', $data);
 }
```

In the view

```xhtml
{%if booleanVariable %}
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
{endif}
```

Comment: codeigniter parser library is simple parser, it just parse only variables here i found extended version of parser check this link you don't need twig or third party library https://gist.github.com/FDiskas/90894d62f566d68a8bb3 how this works check this post https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/68878/P45

Answer (score 0):

it will be different from `twig` , my approach just like so:

```
 public function peajes()
  {
     $data = array(
         'booleanVariable' => true,
      );
     if (ENVIRONMENT==='development') {
       $data['optional']= "happy coding dude :)";
     } else {
       $data['optional']= "";
     }
     $this->parser->parse('myView', $data);
  }
```

in the View do like so, it won't create an error. Because we supply empty string.

```
 <p>
  {optional}
 </p>
```

So AFAIK you can't use if with parser, i hope my approach help you. If you insist use parser try my approach, but if you insist use if on the template you can try use view instead of, [you even can use for in it](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=view#creating-loops)

Answer (score -1):

Just use straight PHP in the view. Like this:

```
<?php if ($booleanVariable) : ?>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```